# What is the fastest way to solve small linear programs inside a loop in MATLAB?

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I'm running `linprog` inside a large time loop to solve small (`m`,`n` <=3) linear programs but it is my code's bottle neck. I found that using Simplex (`Large scale` `'off'`) instead of interior point in the options makes it a little faster. Is there a faster way to do this? matrix `A` is always small and dense (`m`,`n` <= 3). I tried TOMLAB's MINOS and LPOPT and QPOPT but still `linprog` is faster. I don't know maybe I'm not using TOMLAB correctly or that they're just better for large problem sizes.

Is there an easy way to just code a faster LP solver for small problems. For my current problem `linprog` is taking ~.0012 sec for a single iteration to solve 2*2 problems. I have it inside a nested loop, below is a pseudo code:

```
for t =1:nt 
  for n = 1:N 
      linprog 
  end 
end
```

So it would be much better to have it to be as fast as say ~0.0005 sec/iteration. I want to do this before attempting to make the inner loop parallel. The outer loop cannot be made parallel because of dependencies (time loop).

I would highly appreciate any help because my simulations need to be faster than real-time.

Thanks,

Eyas

EDIT: The linear program is of the form :

```
max 1'x 
s.t.  Ax <= b
      lb<=x<=ub
```

`x` and `1` are vectors, we are trying to maximize sum(x), which is why we have an inner product between a vector of ones and `x`. No equality constraints, and `m`,`n` of `A` are both <=3. `A`,`lb` and `ub` change after each `t` and `n` iteration.  Also I'm more interested about the speed up I get with the time loop because `nt`>>`N`, so removing the inner loop by formulating a larger problem will not help much.

Comment: Can you please say a bit more about the linear program you are trying to solve? How many equality constraints? inequality constraints? What changes from iteration to iteration? The objective function? Have you tried different init points `x0`, does this make any difference?

Comment: Found this: Try the solvers 'sqp' or 'active-set'. From http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/linprog.html and then Choosing a solver. Of course using less iterations or a higher tolerance could also speed things up.

Comment: Another thought (completely untested) as matlab likes vectorization and can have serious overhead for small operations it may help to speed things up by combining several small problems into one larger problem. Alternately, if you know that your constraints will always be binding it may be faster to just evaluate all corners of your feasible region.

Comment: @Shai - Sorry I edited the objective function. Yes `x` is a vector and the constraints change for each `t`

Comment: Maybe a "brute force" algorithm might be faster for such small problem sizes. As Dennis suggested, we just evaluate all corners of the feasible region, which should be a small number in my case, I'll try that and see if it's faster.

Comment: @Shai the constraints change with `t` and `n`.

Comment: Create a fixed pipeline version of the simplex algorithm using only scalars; then using element-wise operators (mainly when `/` or `*` are needed) the program is able to handle vectors / multidimensional matrices as well.

Comment: Do you have access to CPLEX or Gurobi? You might try one of their solvers and see if it is faster.

Comment: for `m`,`n`<= `3`, I will have 9 cases for my problem.. I actually tried some cases using a brute force algorithm where i find all feasible corner points and evaluate the objective function then choose the optimal one. I'm getting a lot of speed gain for these small problems.. now it's taking ~ 0.00007 sec/iteration :) , i guess algorithms designed for linear programs of any size have a alot of overhead to find active constraints when compared to the very small number of constraints and dimension in my case.